# array returns unwanted values - php

Tags: php, arrays

It's very fun that my array returns some values that I don't want them and I never added them to it:

```
    foreach ($this->cart as $c) {


        if ($c['parent_id'] != 0) {
            $parent_id = $c['parent_id'];

            if(in_array($parent_id,$checked_parents))
            {
                echo 'true';
            }else
            {

                echo 'parent=>'.$parent_id;
                echo '<br />';
                $checked_parents[] = $parent_id;
                $childes[] = array();
                foreach($this->cart as $c2)
                {


                    if($c2['parent_id'] == $parent_id)
                    {
                        $childes[$c2['id']] = $c2 ;
                        echo 'added'.$c2['id'];
                        echo '<br />';

                    }

                }


                foreach($childes as $k => $v)
                {

                    echo $k ;
                    echo '<br />';
                    if(!$k || $k == 0)
                        continue;
                  ...
                  //my other codes
                  ...
```

my `echo`'s outputs :

```
parent=>16709
added3
0 // unwanted value ?
3
parent=>16710
added2
added1
0 // unwanted value ?
3 // unwanted value ?
4 // unwanted value ?
2 // it's ok
1 // it's ok
true
```

unwanted values :

```
0,3,4
```

why added to my array ?

Comment: You echo out the key here `echo $k ;`

Comment: But `$k` does not equal the `$c2['id']`?

Comment: `$childes[] = array();` you don't initialize the array here, but add an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

just I changed :

```
$childes[] = array();
```

to :

```
unset($childes);
```

Comment: Or you just instantiate the array: `$childes = array();`